# Timeout session in Spring

Tags: java, spring, session

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("userform") UserForm userform, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //if remember-me is checked in the form login
    request.getSession().setMaxInterval(0);

}
```

I have this function, to handle the login action. I want to handle 'remember me' checkbox.I want to set time session when user check "remember me" in the login form. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not use custom logic for Remember-Me authentication. Instead of trying to change max inactive interval of current HTTP session you should set the special "remember-me" cookie that will allow to renew your session automcatically. 
Actually Spring can do it for you. Look at the [example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-remember-me-example/) for better understanding of Remember-Me authentication.